# Switchable AC-DC output

Tags: microcontroller, ac, dc, control, triac

So today I want to make it a little bit strange...

I'm working on a project and there are 4 outputs controlled by 4 relays and the relays' outputs are coming out of the board with phoenix so the user can use them like a switch.

But I'm thinking of putting it in a higher level so the user can choose what every output should be, like this output I want it to be controllable +5V DC (the output set as +5V DC and can be switched on and off with relay) or I want it to be controllable 220V AC so that he can switch on or off this 220V AV output. Notice within just one controllable output we can decide whether it's +5V DC or 220V AC (with a microcontroller).

I'm thinking of using TRIAC.

I don't know if I made my point clear or not but I need your help, if you can help me please don't hesitate and if you didn't get my point tell me which part is not understood so that I make it more clear.

Comment: This is typically a bad idea.  It's best to use keyed ports so something meant for 5v can't physically be plugged into something meant for 220v and vice versa.

Comment: That really does sound like an accident waiting to happen.  Somebody plugs their phone in to charge, and accidentally sets it to 220V AC, not 5V DC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use the same connector for 5V and 220V -- not without killing someone. So just forget about this idea.

> I'm thinking of using TRIAC.

Why do you think about such details before thinking of simple things first, like whether you should even be doing it at all...

Comment: Hi and thanks for your comment, see imagine you have an output and sometimes you want yo control some LEDs and sometimes you want to control a motor and tracks are strong enough. And this need to be done with microcontroller not jumpers. Tnx.